# Google analytics _ga parameter - cross domain

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, analytics

I need help with google analytics cross domain tracking.
On some pages I see forms, when i click submit, google analytics automaticly add hidden field on submit called _ga and send form by get method to other domain. Its some kind of cookie or something that google recognize from where user comes.

So my Problem is Im using aspx and i cant create form because whole document is a form :) I solved it by window.location.href redirect with my input values, but i dont know how to get this _ga parameter... because send form event doesent exists...

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#ready-callback) you can obtain the current client id:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  console.log(tracker.get('clientId'));
});
```

Then you append it to your redirect url as _ga parameter (you still need to configure cross domain tracking by enabling linking etc).

Comment: How do we get it when using Google Tag Manager? I have to do redirect using JavaScript and need to append the _ga parameter.